# Prestashop 1.7.6 The right way to Override a class inside modules src folder

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

i am new to Prestashop and i am trying to override a function of a class inside modules/moduleName/src  in my custom module in override folder but it is not working.

The path of original file is: **modules/moduleName/src/Adapter/file.php**

The path of the changed file is: **modules/myModuleName/override/src/Adapter/file.php**

Extending the class this way it is not woking, it does not use the function of the the changed file.

```
 class MyFileOverride extends MyFile{

        public function myFunction(){
           //funtion to be changed
        }
 }
```

What is the best way to override this file?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Complicated to do. It's not really possible for me...
Otherwise, we can hijack the thing...

The class of your module should extends the class you want to modify and you should change all the calls of the class you want to modify by a call to your class.

Constantin,

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Could you give me a simple example of how to apply this change? Thanks a lot.